# NodeJS with ElasticSearch - keep getting [query_parsing_exception] [range] query does not support [day]

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to run a simple query in nodeJS vs my ElasticSearch:

```
client.search({
    index: "usage_*",
    size : 100,
    from: 0,
    body: {
        query: {
            filtered:{
                filter:{
                    bool:{
                        must: [{"range":{"created":{"gte":{"day":"09","month":"08","year":"2017"},"lt":"now"}}}]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I keep getting an exception with:

> [query_parsing_exception] [range] query does not support [day], with {
>   index="usage_2017-04-01" & line=1 & col=83 } (and)
>   [query_parsing_exception] [range] query does not support [day], with {
>   index="usage_2017-04-02" & line=1 & col=83 } (and)
>   [query_parsing_exception] [range] query does not support [day], with {
>   index="usage_2017-04-03" & line=1 & col=83 } (and)

can someone point me to the problem? I understood that i can write the date as i wrote above(obviously i could write it in other syntax but i am generating this search call using a generic query builder i created)

Answer (score 1):

Your range query is not properly formed, you need to write the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format

```
client.search({
    index: "usage_*",
    size : 100,
    from: 0,
    body: {
        query: {
            filtered:{
                filter:{
                    bool:{
                        must: [{"range":{"created":{"gte":"2017-08-09","lt":"now"}}}]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```