# Elasticsearch Node.js date operators in query search

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm storing data in my local Node JS Elastic Search database, now I've inserted records and one of the fields is a `created_at` field, which I've stored with `new Date()`, however, upon retrieval of the data, it seems that these are Strings, and thus my query doesn't seem to return any results.

My data looks like:

```
{
    "_index": "my_table",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "V1mouXcBt3ZsPNCwd3A1",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 0,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "properties": {
            "created_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            },
            "updated_at": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "name": "performance_overview",
            "friendly_name": "Performance Overview",
            "data": {
                "cached": "9:39:21am",
                "from": "02/19/2021 00:00:00",
                "to": "02/19/2021 23:59:59",
                "success": true,
                "message": "message",
                "sessions": "265",
                "leads": "123",
                "conversion_rate": "46.42"
            },
            "created_at": "2021-02-19 09:02:16",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-19 09:02:16"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Moment JS, and have formatted the dates, and attempted what I believe is accurate for field mappings, although I'm new to Elastic Search and this seems to not return any results either.

```js
const from = moment(from).startOf('day')

const results = await elastic.find('my_table', {
  query: {
    range: {
      created_at: {
        gte: moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'),
      }
    }
  }
})
```

`elastic.find` is a custom function that I've written which looks like the following and is exported from another JS file:

```js
const find = async (table, data) => {
  try {
    const found = await client.search({
      index: table,
      body: data
    }, {
      ignore: [404],
      maxRetries: 3
    })

    return found.body
  } catch (err) {

    return err
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch is a JSON-in, JSON-out interface that stores your datetime data as [strings of a given format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#built-in-date-formats) (could be numeric (milli)seconds since the epoch too, if you choose so.)

As to why `new Date()` was converted to a string — at some point before the network transport, the JS client will [serialize](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/19acc4f9d0f1b96eaea4d759df72f5774341a810/lib/Serializer.js#L31) your documents-containing request body by calling `JSON.stringify` on it. When this function is called on a JS object, the JS runtime looks for an implementation of the [`.toJSON` method on that object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior) and serialize the value returned by the this method. You can verify this by running:

```
const date = new Date();
console.assert(`"${date.toJSON()}"` === JSON.stringify(date))
```

---

Now, in your `elastic.find('my_table', {...})` call you're attempting two things at once — setting the mapping **and** querying the index. That's not going to work.

You've got to [define your mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456701/8160318) *before* you ingest any documents. When you do that, make sure your date fields have [a proper format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#mapping-date-format) to prevent inconsistencies down the line:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "created_at": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    }
  }
}
```

After that add some documents to your table/index (through the [`index` operation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_index)).

Then and only then will you be able to use your `range` query. [Here's a good working example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45607924/8160318).

Comment: This is a useful answer and has sort of helped me in getting data into my table with the `properties` object, however, upon trying to retrieve data, still, nothing is coming through. You can see that the `created_at` field is pretty much right now, and my query is getting the date/time from the start of the day, so there should be results returned, but there isn't. What am I missing?

Comment: It's still not it. The mapping `properties` should not be in the data itself but rather in the index mapping (table schema). What you did is that you put your table schema inside of the table row. Re-read my answer, follow the links (esp. the "define your mapping" part) and see if you get it up and running.

Comment: Did you figure it out @RyanHolton?